# Referencing heap addresses in a machine independent way in C

Tags: c, bitmap, garbage-collection, memory-address

I'm building a garbage collector for a compiler. I work with "physical" and "virtual" addresses. The virtual addresses have type `value_t` and are 32 bits. The physical addresses have type value_t* and are 32 or 64 bits pointers depending on the host machine. The conversion between the two is as follows:

```
static void* addr_v_to_p(value_t v_addr) {
  assert(0 <= v_addr);
  return (char*)memory_start + v_addr;
}

static value_t addr_p_to_v(void* p_addr) {
  assert(memory_start <= p_addr && p_addr <= memory_end);
  return (value_t)((char*)p_addr - (char*)memory_start);
}
```

Then I set a memory lay out similar to this:

[image]

Where the bitmap has to reference values of the heap.

**Problem**

I want to give the index in the bitmap of an address in a machine independent way. (For that purposes it becomes handy to set `VALUE_BITS = sizeof(value_t) * CHAR_BITS` as the number of bits of the `value_t` type). I would write:

```
(ptr, heap_start, bitmap_start of type value_t*)
size_t index = ptr - heap_start;
size_t word_index = index / VALUE_BITS;
bitmap_start[word_index] = ...;
```

But I'm not sure this is going to work.

Comment: So each bit in the bitmap corresponds to one byte / address in the heap?

Comment: What is the type of a physical address? Description says value_t*, code looks like void*.

Comment: But you seem to be asking why your own code is written as it is.  The most we could do is offer educated guesses.  Don't *you* know?

Comment: Is this *your* code, or it is not?

Comment: Looking at your updated question, I guess you're asking "will my proposed code work?"  You haven't given us enough information to judge -- in particular we would need to see *at least* the type of `bitmap_start`.  But since you're posing the question in the first place, what's the nature of *your* uncertainty about it?

Comment: Actually the comments by John Bollinger and Yunnosch have made me think about the template I was given in a different way. I'll edit when I clarify my ideas on it. Thanks.

Comment: When you say that the virtual addresses have type `value_t` and are 32 bits, are you assuming that none of those 32 are padding bits?  And does this mean that `value_t` is certain to be an unsigned type?

Comment: To use the suggested method of working with the heap, your code would need to know how the OS is handling the heap allocation and free functionality.  (Unless your planning on replacing all the heap allocation an free functions with your own functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, your "bitmap" is intended to be sequence of bits, with a unique bit corresponding to each heap address.  Presumably you also want to minimize the number of unused bits.  You are asking about your proposed approach to mapping between heap addresses and bits.

Furthermore, the conversion functions you present between virtual and physical addresses suggest that your memory model is byte-addressible, as opposed, say, to being addressible only with the granularity of a `value_t`.

Since your bitmap is apparently accessed in units of type `value_t`, which I'm taking to be unsigned and without padding bits, the number of usable bits in each unit is `sizeof(value_t) * CHAR_BIT`.  That matches your `VALUE_BITS`, modulo spelling.  Still, if `bitmap_start` is going to be (or reasonably can be made to be) visible wherever `VALUE_BITS` is defined (if it is a variable) or used (if it is a macro), then I would be inclined to write its initializer / replacement text as `(sizeof(*bitmap_start) * CHAR_BIT)`.  That's clearer to me and adapts automatically if ever you change the type to which `bitmap_start` points.

---

Now let's consider your code starting with this:

> ```
> size_t index = ptr - heap_start;
> ```

There's nothing inherently wrong with that, but remember that pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of units of the pointed-to type.  Thus, that gives the number of units of type `value_t` in the half-open interval defined by the two pointers, supposing `ptr` points into or just past the end of the heap *and is properly aligned*.  That alignment caveat matters because your model is byte-addressible, therefore there are valid values that `ptr` can take that are misaligned.  In fact, the majority of valid `ptr` values are misaligned.  If you want the index in terms of a *byte* offset into the heap -- and it appears you do -- then you want something more like this:

```
ptrdiff_t index = (char *) ptr - (char *) heap_start;
```

---

Let's move on to the next part:

> ```
> size_t word_index = index / VALUE_BITS;
> ```

It seems you're trying to determine the storage unit in the bitset that contains the `index`<sup>th</sup> bit.  If we stipulate that each unit contains `VALUE_BITS` usable bits, and that you want every bit in each unit to correspond to a heap address, then this is fine.

But you seem to have run out of steam there, as this ...

> ```
> bitmap_start[word_index] = ...;
> ```

... is slightly lacking in detail.  You're going to need to use bit masking to select the appropriate bit of `bitmap_start[word_index]` to examine or set, and in doing so you'll need to take care to avoid modifying the other bits in the same unit.  That's not hard, but I'm not going to do it for you.